# Нужна ли запятая после "по закону"?

Tags: пунктуация

По закону, ребенок, которому исполнилось десять лет, должен написать заявление, согласен ли он жить у людей, которые хотят стать его приемными родителями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не нужна:

> По закону ребенок, которому исполнилось десять лет, должен написать заявление, согласен ли он жить у людей, которые хотят стать его приемными родителями.

Слова *по закону* не являются вводными и не обособляются.
Возможно, в предложение стоит добавить *о том* перед словом *согласен*: *заявление о том, согласен ли*. 
Источник: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83.